# Active Model Serializer produces wrong ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, serialization

If you use `Active Model Serializers` to generate a JSON API in Rails, see [RailsCast 409](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers), and define a `serializer` like this..

```
class ArticleSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :name, :content
end
```

..and try to serialize the object (usually by `render :json => article`):

```
ArticleSerializer.new(article).as_json
=>  {:id=>158655280, :name => "a name", :content => "article content"}
```

then it produces sometimes very weird IDs and a warning: `Object#id will be deprecated; use Object#object_id`, at least for Ruby 1.8.7, Ruby 1.9.3 seems to work.

**Is this a Ruby problem?**

How can you fix it if updating to Ruby 1.9.3 is not an option?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. The solution was to define an id method in my serializer:

```
def id
  object.id
end
```